# VS2017: E0135 namespace "std" has no member "filesystem"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++17, std-filesystem

In order to use: `std::filesystem` from the C++17 library, my project was migrated from vs2015 to vs2017.

My project compiles and runs without error, the lib is included without error, but when trying to use `std::filesystem` I get the following:

[image: 1]

It seems the library is not being included but cant see why not?

Edit:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.7.3+27703.2026
Visual C++ 2017   00369-90000-00000-AA466
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

A couple of options to investigate.

- Check the language standard. You need C++17 or above:
  [image]
  [image]
- If your version of visual studio doesn't support `std::filesystem` yet, you can try `std::experimental::filesystem`.

I have the following version and `std::filesystem` works (with the C++17 language selection shown above):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview
Version 15.8.0 Preview 1.1
VisualStudio.15.Preview/15.8.0-pre.1.1+27705.2000
```

Comment: That setting in your pic was blank when I checked, making it the same as yours resolved the issue, you saved me hours of heartache there Wally TVM!

Comment: Thank you very much. works perfectly for me. In my case its the `std::any` that is missing

Comment: I have got fully updated vs2017 and std::filesystem does not work. Any idea?

Comment: @shout I updated from vs2017 15.4 or something to 15.9, and updated my windows SDK from 10.16 to 10.17 and restarted vs2017 and it works for me.

Comment: please provide a like for vs 2017 comparability with std ::filesystem

Comment: I would like to add that in VS 2019 you need to put the debug mode on x64 on top of setting C++ 2017 as the standard.

Comment: MaestroMau can you explain this in more detail? Because I am using 2019 and I do not find the second option you mention. Setting C++17 is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

I had a common issue, that **filesystem** was not recognized as **std** member for Linux environment only (on Windows it was fine).

For me adding the `#include <filesystem>` in the .hpp file as well solved the problem (although in theory, I didn't need this include there).

Comment: Don't know why and how, but it helped. Thanks!

Comment: I had the problem on Windows. This solved it.